# Reading Each line from a TextFile and adding it to a ListBox C#

Tags: c#, listbox

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(this.textBox2.Text);
     foreach (string line in lines)
     {
          this.listProxy.Items.Add(lines);
     }
}
```

When I click the button it is not writing it out to the `ListBox`.

How can I make it add each line in order to the `ListBox`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your should use `line` instead `lines`

```
this.listProxy.Items.Add(line);
```

look the code edited below:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(this.textBox2.Text);
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        this.listProxy.Items.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is for a System.Windows.Forms.ListBox you could skip the foreach and use listProxy.Items.AddRange(lines);

Answer (score 0):

First, for whta i see in the code provided you are getting text from textbox and not from a TextFile.

Second, make sure that the TextFile you are going to use, contains information.

Third, you could use a try catch block in order to detect errors and be able to correct them before sending this to production.

Comment: It looks to me like he's getting the filename from the textbox